# Python output RETURN not working in an Api key sms script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a python script that returns an account information from API Key 
The website : pvasms.com
**Tutorial in pvasms.com** : http://smspva.com/new_theme_api.html
**I've found 2 scripts already on github :** 
https://github.com/ooojustin/smspva/blob/master/smspva/smsrequest.py
https://github.com/alihossein/smspva/blob/master/SmsPva.py

I've tried both of them, i've replaced value with my Api Key, when i run : 0 Error but it didn't return anything

```
    import requests


class SmsPva:
    def __init__(self):
        self._url = 'http://smspva.com/priemnik.php'
        self._api_key = 'myapikey'
        self._method_type = 'get'
        self._query_string = {}

    def get_number(self, id=1, country='ru', service='opt29'):
        """
        Request for receiving a phone number for a certain service
        :return:
        """
        self._query_string = {'metod': 'get_number', 'country': country, 'service': service, 'id': id,
                              'apikey': self._api_key}
        result = self.__make_request()
        return result

    def get_sms(self, id, country='ru', service='opt29'):
        """
        Receiving a SMS for a certain service
        :return:
        """
        self._query_string = {'metod': 'get_sms', 'country': country, 'service': service, 'id': id,
                              'apikey': self._api_key}
        result = self.__make_request()
        return result

    def get_balance(self, service='opt29'):
        """
        User's balance request
        :param service:
        :return:
        """
        self._query_string = {'metod': 'get_balance', 'service': service, 'apikey': self._api_key}
        result = self.__make_request()
        return result

    def get_userinfo(self, service='opt29'):
        """
        User's balance request and karma (Your rating)
        :return:
        """
        self._query_string = {'metod': 'get_userinfo', 'service': service, 'apikey': self._api_key}
        result = self.__make_request()
        return result

    def get_count_new(self, service='opt29', country='ru'):
        """
        Request for the amount of free activations for a certain service
        :param country:
        :param service:
        :return:
        """
        self.query_string = {'metod': 'get_count_new', 'service': service, 'country': country, 'apikey': self._api_key}
        result = self.__make_request()
        return result

    def denial(self, id, country='ru', service='opt29'):
        """
        Cancel the order to number you got
        :return:
        """
        self._query_string = {'metod': 'denial', 'country': country, 'service': service, 'id': id,
                              'apikey': self._api_key}
        result = self.__make_request()
        return result

    def __make_request(self):
        """
        make request post or get , ...
        :return:
        """

        try:
            if self._method_type == 'get':
                response = requests.get(self._url, self._query_string)
            elif self._method_type == 'post':
                pass

            if response.status_code == 200:
                return response.json()
            else:
                return response

        except Exception as e:
            return e
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first change all country and service parts in code to what you want and then look at the methods in the class (like get_number) and the comments below them and see which one do you want to use. when you did these two steps write this underneath the code (without any indentations)

```
request = SmsPva
request.get_number() # change get_number with any other methods in the class that you want
# you can do the last line over and over with other methods
```

and then you can get the output by using print function like this:

```
print(request.get_number())
```

and finally I recommend learning python in the future ;)

Comment: I'm still a beginner, i only master python selenium, 
This is my first time working with api key so i took the ready scripts (in the links) and tried them .
What do you mean by call methods

Comment: You should make an object `sms = SmsPva` and then call one of the functions(methods of the class) like `sms.get_number()` or print it if you want to see some result (put it inside print function)

Comment: Can you please edit the code for me, or just a demonstration of lines i should add 
i will be so grateful

Comment: can you tell me what do you actually want?(look in the first link you posted in question). I don't know what this website do

Comment: We have a class project, we need to create a script that retreive information from this website from the Api Key
The teacher provided us with the tutorial link of smspva and now we are working on it

Comment: With this website : we can rent virtual phone numbers in order to get sms verification and verify some websites/ applications like snapchat ...